# set gap between text and icon of command

Tags: codenameone

I am using command with text and icon and want to set gap between them
I try to setGap but the method is not available

```
command.setGap();
```

so how can set the gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
command.putClientProperty("iconGap", new Integer(gap));
```